# React useEffect only works if I make a change to the code once the page is open

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm having a problem in React where the code I have for my useEffect in a component works, but *only* if I manually make a change to the code (not even a substantial one, it can be as small as adding or removing a console.log) after loading the component. [Here's a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12EtuxhY5PRcx6kHKMx3c8YNxKXnX3Paj/view) to a screen recording of what happens.

I am using the [Material-UI Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) component to create a list, but it's like the useEffect won't actually kick in when I load the page with the component until I make some sort of change to the code *after* the component loads (again: even something as small as commenting out or adding a console.log works). Once I make that change, the list will appear. But if I navigate away from the page or reload, I'm back to square 1 again.

Similarly, when I try to select an option in the list, it looks as if it didn't work until I make a change to the code. Only then will the selection change I made to the list appear.

Here's the code I have for that component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'

import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank'
import CheckBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBox'

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize='small' />
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize='small' />

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    margin: 'auto'
  },
  paper: {
    width: 250,
    height: 230,
    overflow: 'auto',
    backgroundColor: '#bdbdbd'
  },
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(0.5, 0)
  },
  checkbox: {
    color: '#FFF342'
  },
  textfield: {
    backgroundColor: '#bdbdbd'
  }
}))

const WordSelect = ({ newListState, setNewListState }) => {
// const WordSelect = ({ newListState, setNewListState }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  const [wordsText, setWordsText] = useState({
    wordOptions: []
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    const wordsText = []

    newListState.words.map(x => {
      wordsText.push(x.text)
    })

    // console.log(wordsText)

    setWordsText({ ...wordsText, wordOptions: wordsText })
  }, []) // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps


  return (
    <>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id='checkboxes-tags-demo'
        disableCloseOnSelect
        value={newListState.selected}
        options={wordsText.wordOptions}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
        getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option === value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          newListState.selected = newValue
        }}
        renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
          <>
            <Checkbox
              className={classes.checkbox}
              icon={icon}
              checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
              style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
              checked={selected}
            />
            <Typography className={classes.checkbox}>
              {option}
            </Typography>
          </>
        )}
        style={{ width: 500 }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} className={classes.textfield} variant='outlined' placeholder='Select Words' />
        )}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default WordSelect
```

I'm really not sure what's going on. It seems like the code must be right since the types of changes I make to get it to show up should have no effect on what renders on the page, but then why won't it render from the start? Any tips appreciated.

Comment: could it be a race condition? is `newListState` always defined on the first render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added newListState to your useEffect dependency array. Therefore, useEffect runs only on the first render of the component. When you do a change in code, live reload reloads the component and the useEffect hook runs.

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const wordsText = []

    newListState.words.map(x => {
      wordsText.push(x.text)
    })

    // console.log(wordsText)

    setWordsText({ ...wordsText, wordOptions: wordsText })
  }, [setWordsText, newListState])
```

You really shouldn’t be using ‘  // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps’ as it helps catch problems like these. It also might help you catch some nasty bugs due to stale data or functions.

Comment: Thanks! This helped with the first part of the problem. The list of words now appears on the autocomplete drop down. Although it's still not showing any changes to the list until I update the code.

Edit (hit enter by accident):

I have never really known what those square brackets at the end of the useEffect are for. I'm very new at coding and know just enough to get myself in trouble. LOL. The eslint bit I just found as a solution when I googled an error message I was getting.

Comment: Try going through the React documentation to get a better grasp of how hooks like useEffect work. https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html#learn-react

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.

For the record, I figured out my problem for the second part where it didn't update the selected data. When I was setting the newValue, I didn't use the right format. I was using the commented out line, but the line above it is how I should have done it.

`
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setNewListState({ ...newListState, selected: newValue })
          // newListState.selected = newValue
        }}
`